# Microsoft office 365 single signone

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, single-sign-on, openid

I want to implement Single Sign On(SSO) for our web-application using Microsoft office 365. After research I found that OpenID is the best approach for us.
Inside our application user can have access to OneDrive and Microsoft team.
And the aim of using SSO is after login user automatically logged-in to OneDrive and M-team too.
But I am not sure what is the best approach here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use OpenIDConnect to do so. Also, i would suggest you to consider the [native MSAL (Microsoft Authentication library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview). Say your web application uses javascript then you can use MSAL.js (as it has various flavors), using that implement SSO so you can work seamlessly with Azure Active Directory + OneDrive + Microsoft Teams using Microsoft Graph API. Here's a [related sample using MSAL.js + SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso).